# Zammad integration to 3CX

Tags: integration, 3cx, zammad

I will like to integrate a **Zammad** installation to **3CX PBX**. 
I found how to do it on the **3CX** documentation but, I didn't found a great suggestion.

Am open for more suggestion especially a great example.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried and it worked for me. it's  an implementation off zammad but more in the the 3CX softphone. We get the number from the incoming call or outgoing call from the 3CX softphone before it's received by the agent or customer.

I created a batch script  to search the number picked from the 3CX softphone in Zammad, Making use of the search function in zammad since users and tickets will have this number recorded, the Agent will get a pop in the default web browser of the search results in Zammad.

To connect the batch script to 3CX navigate to 3CX settings > select Advanced Settings and then select > Behavior > Tick the Launch Application on incoming call and also select the path where the batch script is saved.

Below are the commands to be saved in the batch script that will be executed every time a call is made in 3CX and it will open up a default web browser

Kindy note that you can add-in more API calls in the batch script as you wish to complete your required workflow

> ::3CXURL_launcher ***takes number as param 
>  @echo OFF
>  set
> param=%1
>  set url1=https://zammad_domain_url/#search/
>  set
> full=%url1%%param%
>  @echo ON
>  @start %full%

[image]